# Can Java 9 JPMS be used with SPI to dynamically load plugins at runtime?

Tags: java, plugins, spi

I have a Java 8 project that requires the use of plugins. These are jars that can be placed in a specific directory, and if present can be used by the main application.

The plan is to achieve this using Java 8 SPI, as detailed here: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/spi.html

So far so good. However, I'd like to be able to pick up new plugins placed in that dir at runtime, without having to restart the application. The above link (written for Java 8) states:

> Also, the current ServiceLoader class cannot tell your application when new providers are available at runtime. Additionally, you cannot add change-listeners to the loader to find out whether a new provider was placed into an application-specific extension directory.

Some changes to this mechanism are introduced in Java 9 JPMS, including not needing to (source: https://dzone.com/articles/java-platform-module-systemjpms-migration-guide-fo) create files under META-INF/services to advertise Implementations.

So the question is : would migrating to Java 9 enable me to scan my plugins directory at runtime and make any new ones available? Is there another alternative to achieve this in Java 8 ? I know of OSGI but it seems overkill for my purposes.

Many thanks for any answers/insight you might have!!